# Angular 2 - Invoke component without rendering it

Tags: angular

I am using **UniqueValidation** that checks if the entered value already exists inside a **GridComponent**.

The grid in this case serves only as a validation tool and should not be rendered anywhere.

Note that I unable to know which service is filling the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to wrap the **GridComponent** template with an

`<div *ngIf="visible"></div>`

When I use validation, I set the visible to false.

I am using `DynamicComponentLoader` to load the component and after I'm done validating, I call `componentRef.dispose()` to get rid of the component

Answer (score 1):

> The grid in this case serves only as a validation tool and should not be rendered anywhere.

Then it should not be a component in the first place. In your case it makes sense to move the actual validation logic into a reusable service and use this service whenever you need to validate anything anywhere without rendering.

Comment: Is there any way to dynamically get the service that fills the grid

Comment: It only serves as a validation tool for this case, If somebody clicks the magnifying glass it will give him the option to select the value he wants from the grid